# How to generate a md5 hash for an htpasswd file in PHP when I don't have the plaintext

Tags: php, linux, apache, encryption, hash

I have records in my database for users passwords encrypted with md5. I'd like to have PHP add those encrypted passwords to the htpasswd file. But I've read that the htpasswd file uses an MD5 algorithm that is repeated 1000 times and salted. I've found plenty of examples online for how to create this hash from the plaintext, but in this case, I don't have the plaintext. I'm trying to generate the htpasswd hash starting with the already encrypted md5 hash. Should I write my own code to hash it 999 more times, and salt it? How do I do this?

This is on a Linux server with PHP 5 and MySQL.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: not possible. You cannot "decrypt" the hash. You could bruteforce something that "collides" and produces the same hash, but it won't necessarily  be the exact same text as the password was, and a collision that works for md5 is extremely unlikely to work in any other hash algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to store MD5 based hashes in `.htpasswd`: standard md5crypt and Apache's own MD5 hashing. The two algorithms are identical, but they use different magic string constants.

They're based on md5'ing 1000 times as you say, but if you [look closely at the algorithm](http://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=32), you'll see that it appends the plaintext password in each iteration.

It's not just `md5(md5(md5(...))))`, but a rather convoluted `md5(password+salt+password+md5(md5(...)+salt+password+password))`.

Therefore, to calculate a `.htpasswd` md5 password, you need the actual plaintext password. `md5(password)` doesn't help you at all.

---

So what can you do instead?

- You can use a different form of Apache authentication, such as [mod_auth_form](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_form.html), to do your own authentication against your database. This would probably have been the best choice anyways.
- By storing `md5(password)` in the database, you've introduced a huge security hole. You (and any attacker) can use a GPGPU based md5 cracker to get the plaintext for most of them in a day.
- You can ask the user to change their password on next login, giving you a plaintext password, and you can take the opportunity to fix that security hole.

Comment: Thanks so much, this completely answers my question! :)